# return array with characternumer in WSDL

Tags: php, xml, web-services, wsdl

Using Web Service in PHP need to return an array::

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0100
        [1] => 0101-01-000741 
        [2] => 0101
        [3] => 0101ABM1704621
        [4] => 0101-256-01-04-00133     
        [5] => 2.5000
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0100
        [1] => 0101-01-000443 
        [2] => 0101
        [3] => 0101ABY2211791
        [4] => 0101-256-01-00-00130     
        [5] => 2.5000
    )
```

When you get the array can not treat [3] => 0101ABY2211791 position, the server extracts the data but do not return the WSDL data.

How I can recover that data through WSDL?

My WSDL is:

```
    <wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="urn:Aritmetica">
      <xsd:complexType name="resultArray">
        <complexContent>
          <restriction base="SOAP-ENC:Array">
            <attribute ref="SOAP-ENC:arrayType"
                       wsdl:arrayType="xsd:string[][]"/>
          </restriction>
        </complexContent>
      </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:schema>
    </wsdl:types>

    <message name="AritmeticaPeticion">
    <part name="operando1" type="xsd:string" />
  </message>

  <message name="AritmeticaRespuesta">
    <part name="respuesta" type="xsd:resultArray" />
  </message>
```

Comment: What's the code + output you get when using WSDL?

Comment: It is a white screen

Comment: I think the problem is to receive an array [] [] that the receive array [] gives me [3] => 0101ABY2211791